# swiper js flickering after few seconds if using fade effect

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, swiper.js

im using the latest version (version 10) of swiper js, when i using slider for images, it will flickering after few seconds. This only happens if im using fade effets `effect: "fade"`. Is there a solution for this problem?

[image]